# How to disable write caching on windows 8 drive via command line

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive-cache

In the properties of a disk drive in windows 7/8/8.1 there are two Write-caching 'policies' that can be set. 
I've found disabling 'Enable write caching on this device' significantly improves the reliability of systems that are subject to unexpected hard power cycles.

I'm looking for a way to disable this option in some sort of automated fashion.
I'll be writing it into a batch script, so either something command line or vbs would work.

Comment: Here is some information about your problem. Including the registry setting and a script fully detailed: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/10/09/enable-or-disable-enable-write-caching-on-disk-behavior-on-disk.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be a native, built-in cli executable to perform what you're asking but Microsoft's **dskcache** utility available [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/811392) should be able to accomplish what you seek.

A little tip: If you're trying to find a way to accomplish something in Windows without using the GUI, try searching with the words 'Windows Core', as that version of Windows has no GUI by default.

In essence, search for `windows core task-you-wish-to-accomplish`